# Как сделать относительный путь для файла из другого модуля через api?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть Класс в одном из модулей.
В другом соседнем модуле есть xml файл с которым я работаю

Как перейти от абсолютного пути к относительному, решение вида ../../file.xml не работает. Мне посоветовали положить xml в ресурсы и использоваться api. Что за Api, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Этот вопрос стоило задать тому, кто посоветовал вам API.

Comment: зависит от  того, где лижит xml файл и откуда(из какой директории) запускаете выполнение программы